# display all nodes of a specific type postman(d8 site)

Tags: postman, drupal-8

I have a content type as `dealers`. I'm trying to display all nodes created under `dealers` type in postman. Though I could display a specific node by using - `/entity/node/{nid}?_format=json`, but not all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the trial-and-error method, I found that, `http://localhost:XXXX/restapi/node/dealers` gave me all the dealers.